# Why does the for attribute from the label tag is not working in userControl.ascx?

Tags: c#, css, file-upload, webusercontrol

i Have this line of code :

```
<label id="lblinput" class="input-label" runat="server" for="fUpload">
<i class="fa fa-upload" aria-hidden="true"></i>
<span id="label-span">Select files to upload</span></label>
<asp:FileUpload ID="fUpload" runat="server" AllowMultiple="true" CssClass="fUpload"/>
```

and is placed inside a usercontrol, which i load in a modal to load files into a database. I wanted to style the button for choosing files so i hid it and gave the label it's id .. as i understand that is the only way to style the FileUpload controller from asp.
the problem is that it does not work when placed in a usercontrol .. i tried it in a regular aspx page and it works there. Do you have any idea why that is ?
thank you :)

> Solved:

i added ClientIDMode and set it to static in the asp:FileUpload and it works now

Comment: What id is the control getting in the rendered HTML? It might be related to the ClientIdMode property https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: thank you! i looked over the website you gave and i needed to set the ClientIdMode to static and now it works like a charm